# Function which copies an array of integers from one array to another using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

The purpose of the `Copy` function in the following code is to copy an array of integers from one array to another using C++ but the output seems wrong.

What could be the problem here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Copy(int old_array[],int new_array[],int length)
{
    int *ptr1 = old_array;
    int *ptr2 = new_array;
    int i = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<length ; i++)
    {
        *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <2; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(ptr2 + i)<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a[2]={0,1};
    int b[2];
    Copy(a,b,2);
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: `memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));` -- That uses pointers.

Comment: Think about what `ptr2` points to after the first loop

Comment: Consider using `std::vector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr2` is one past the end of the array when your print loop runs.

Try this:

```
void Copy(int old_array[], int new_array[], int length)
{
    int* ptr1 = old_array;
    int* ptr2 = new_array;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    }
    ptr2 = new_array;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << *(ptr2 + i) << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ptr2` is pointing to the element `b[2]` (which is out-of-bound access) at the time you are printing it in the second for loop.

You can fix it by subtracting the `length` from the `ptr2` in the second for loop like below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Copy(int old_array[],int new_array[],int length)
{
    int *ptr1 = old_array;
    int *ptr2 = new_array;
    int i = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<length ; i++)
    {
        *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <2; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(ptr2 + i - length)<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a[2]={0,1};
    int b[2];
    Copy(a,b,2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The copy seems fine but the second for is accessing ptr2 which was incremented in the first for and is point to some invalid memory position. You could use new_array in this second loop.
I suppose this second loop is only for debug and will be better located in the main using, in you case, the variable b.